# This program is going into infinite loop

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;
int buf[20];

void main(){
    int x = 3;
    for(i = 6; i < 12; i+2){
        buf[i] = 5;
        printf("print1 : %d \n", i);
        buf[i+1] = 5;
        printf("print 2 :%d \n", i);
   }

   for(i = 6; i < 12; i++){
       printf("%d\n", buf[i]);
   }

}
```

This code in going into infine loop and prints only
print 1 :6 
 print 2 :6. 
why?

Comment: increment `i` in the first loop :)

Answer (score 5):

Because you dont modify `i`.

Change `for(i = 6; i < 12; i+2)` to :

```
for(i = 6; i < 12; i+=2)
                    ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not store the value back into `i` here `for(i = 6; i < 12; i+2)` do this

```
for(i = 6; i < 12; i=i+2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `i + 2` is an expression that does not modify the variable `i` which is used for the termination condition of the loop. Simply change it to `i += 2` to increment i by two.